# How do I make a event that check when a user comes online?

Tags: discord.py

```
async def on_member_update(member, status):
  if str(member.status) == "online":
    print(f"{member} has gone {status}.")
```

The code runs just fine but it wont update when I update my status or someone else changes theres.

Answer (score 0):

`on_member_update` only takes before and after as parameters, not member or status.

Something like this should work:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if str(after.status) == "online":
        print(f"{after.name} has gone {after.status}.")
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_update#discord.on_member_update

Comment: What do you mean by that? All I can say is I tested it myself with this code and it works for me. Can you maybe show the full event listener?

Comment: Did you add the `@bot.event` decorator above your listener? Edited my code accordingly

Comment: That's because you haven't enabled the member gateway intent on the discord dev portal.

Comment: @LUNA also it has to be activated in code along with the portal

Comment: You also need to enable presences intents

Comment: @Abdulaziz I know.

Comment: I enabled presences intents though-